# "A very long letter was written to him " & "He was written a very long letter"

Tags: passive-voice

Is there a difference between these two sentences?

> A very long letter was written to him

> He was written a very long letter

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question falls into the pattern of "What is the difference between X & Y?" You may be interested in this post for advice about how you can improve such questions: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Comment: No difference in meaning, but the second one should include "TO". "He was written to a very ....."

Comment: @yunus - No - that would mean that someone wrote him to a letter!

Comment: @KateBunting, Longman dictionary shows "write to", LETTER [intransitive, transitive] to put words in a letter to someone. And here is an example from the dictionary: "I’ve written to my MP, and to the city council."

Comment: @yunus And those examples don't include the direct object "letter" because "write" is *intransitive* in that example. You're wrong, and Kate is right.

Comment: OK, I understand it now. Thanks Kate. I have learnt a new thing in English.

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate meanings are approximately the same, even though the two sentences have been organized differently. Grammatically, "letter" is the object, "he/him" is the indirect object.

Both use the passive voice and obscure the identity of the writer. The clearest and most understandable phrasing is the active construction. "Bresson wrote him a very long letter."   It's even tempting to say "You should prefer the active voice. Don't use the passive voice this way unless you have a compelling reason to do so". But in fact, understanding and applying the passive voice is necessary in many situation.